# What is the typical level of indirection between a controller and a view in mvc and similar architectures?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, indirection

So say I make a controller for a main menu 'page', would MainMenu be composed of the individual view elements like labels and buttons directly or would it reference a class such as MainMenuView which had those elements instead? Or would it just send events to an event system to communicate with the view? Or something else?

Comment: Your mention of "events" makes me wonder how familiar you are with MVC at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons and labels would most likely be in the `View`, although labels can come from the `Controller`. Normally a `View` is just the html scaffolding, and the data that the `View` contains is populated from the `Model` by the `Controller`. So for a main menu, it's probably going to just be links and labels to other sections so there probably won't be a `Model` for it, the `Controller` will just return the `View`.

So if someone went to `SomeMVCSite.com/home/index`, the `Index Action` would be called in the `Home Controller`. The `Home Controller` would retrieve data from the database based on a `Model` and return the `View` + the data.